# Journey Builder Wait Activity Clarification

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm creating a journey with multiple wait activities but need clarification as to when the activity ends.

Example:
Email A is scheduled to deploy on 5/1. After the email deploys there is a 3 day wait activity followed by the deployment of Email B. Does that mean that email B deploys on 5/4 or 5/5?

Essentially, does the wait activity run for 3 full days after the deploy (waiting 5/2, 5/3, and 5/4, deploying on 5/5), or does wait 3 full days *immediately* following the deploy of Email A. So if Email A deploys at 9am on 5/1, does the wait activity end at 9am on 5/4 meaning Email B deploys at 9am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in the documentation, "Its expiration date and time is the time a contact reaches the wait activity plus the duration configured in the activity."  So if it reaches the wait activity at 9am on 5/1, the timer (for lack of better words begins).  So it would play out like this:

- 5/1 @ 9AM: Contact entered wait activity
- 5/2 @ 9AM: 24 hours in wait activity (Day 1)
- 5/3 @ 9AM: 48 hours in wait activity (Day 2)
- 5/4 @ 9AM: 72 hours passed - Contact exits wait period